# Multiple TIKZ-UML usecase not showing correctly when included in document

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-uml

I'm using TIKZ-UML to create four simple usecase diagrams. I have made them individually in seperate files to make sure that they all compile as they should.

I include the required packages in my preamble and include a reference to the files containing the tikzpictures in my document. When I compile the first diagram it compiles (and shows) just fine, but the following three diagrams seem to be affected by a width stated in a \usecase of the first diagram.

This diagram is the first one that is included in the document:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}

\umlactor[y=4]{Supervisor}
\umlactor[y=2]{Co-Supervisor}
\umlactor[y=0]{Examinator}

\umlusecase[x=5, y=2, fill=lightgray!50, width=3cm]{Determining examiner availability}

\umlactor[x=10, y=2]{Secretary}

\umlassoc{Supervisor}{usecase-1}
\umlassoc{Co-Supervisor}{usecase-1}
\umlassoc{Examinator}{usecase-1}

\umlassoc{usecase-1}{Secretary}

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Scenario: Determining examiner availbility.}
\end{figure}
```

The other diagrams are much the same, only with a different text for the \usecase (and possibly an other width.

The preamble for the diagram contains:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,chains,fit,shapes,calc}
```

Link to example:
[First diagram OK, next one has the wrong width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCLO8.jpg)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you always refer to `usecase-1` in your associations. The names and counters are global, however, so in your second `tikzpicture`, you should be referring to `usecase-2`.

The nodes and anchors are defined globally, so even though you didn't define a `usecase-1` in your second picture, you can still refer to it as if you had, and the lines will end up at the same positions as in your first picture.

Alternatively, you can just reset the counter `tikzumlUseCaseNum` to `0` at the start of every new `tikzpicture`, so the numbering will start again:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,chains,fit,shapes,calc}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\umlactor[y=4]{Supervisor}
\umlactor[y=2]{Co-Supervisor}
\umlactor[y=0]{Examinator}

\umlusecase[x=5, y=2, fill=lightgray!50, width=3cm]{Determining examiner availability}

\umlactor[x=10, y=2]{Secretary}

\umlassoc{Supervisor}{usecase-1}
\umlassoc{Co-Supervisor}{usecase-1}
\umlassoc{Examinator}{usecase-1}

\umlassoc{usecase-1}{Secretary}

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\setcounter{tikzumlUseCaseNum}{0}% Reset the counter
\umlactor[y=4]{Supervisor}
\umlactor[y=2]{Co-Supervisor}
\umlactor[y=0]{Examinator}

\umlusecase[x=5, y=2, fill=lightgray!50, width=2cm]{Sudden}

\umlactor[x=10, y=2]{Secretary}

\umlassoc{Supervisor}{usecase-1}
\umlassoc{Co-Supervisor}{usecase-1}
\umlassoc{Examinator}{usecase-1}

\umlassoc{usecase-1}{Secretary}

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your well-explained answer!
Is there a way to explicitly name a node and then reference it instead of using the name for the node as a reference?
For example, I reference the actor "Supervisor" as "Supervisor" - sometimes it would be nice to give such node a destinct name and another "id".

Comment: @thilemann: Certainly! You can just add `name=<your name>` to the options of `\umlusecase`.

Comment: I was about to lose my sanity on this one, trying and trying different approaches to fix it, until I used the right keywords for searching and found your answer. Thank you!